# How to create constant for the values inside an array and access them outside class in php

Tags: php

I have created array inside a class  using constant and assigned values to that array  by key,value pair so I want to create const for a,const for b,const for c  values, so how  to create this and access those values(a,b,c) outside class using Php? actually I am not getting any output for this.

```
<?php  

class foo {

    const arrayOfvalues = [
        'a' => 'text for  a',
        'b' => 'text for b',
        'c' => 'text for c'

    ]; 
    const for_avalue= foo::arrayOfvalues[0];  //create constant for a
    const for_bvalue= foo::arrayOfvalues[0];  //create constant for b
    const for_cvalue= foo::arrayOfvalues[0];  //create constant for c

}
echo 'current const value'. for_avalue;  //call a value by its constant name

?>
```

Comment: That won't work, it is against the idea of a const to be assigned in a dynamic manner.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to use the correct `indexes` and also to call the `class`. Although I don't understand why you want to create constants in this way, here comes the correct version of your current code:

```
class foo {

    const arrayOfvalues = [
        'a' => 'text for  a',
        'b' => 'text for b',
        'c' => 'text for c'

    ]; 
    const for_avalue= foo::arrayOfvalues['a'];  //create constant for a
    const for_bvalue= foo::arrayOfvalues['b'];  //create constant for b
    const for_cvalue= foo::arrayOfvalues['c'];  //create constant for c

}
echo 'current const value'. foo::for_avalue;
```

Comment: what is wrong by creating this way I mean I want to create constant for every values inside array, so i thought that using way it is possible

Comment: I am new to this thing so will you please tell me the correct way to make constant for this because I want to learn more about this and want to implement in project